# ¿Es "Que sí/ Que no" incorrecto o agresivo como respuesta a una pregunta?

Tags: gramática, vocabulario, modismos, preguntas, formalidad

Mandé a un amigo esta frase (en el medio de una conversación más larga)

***Que sí, lo he probado***

Me ha respondido mi amigo

***cuando dices 'que sí', es incorrecto, además suena 'agresivo', como si estuvieras 'cansado'***

Yo creía 'que sí' era una afirmativa, como "Yes" en inglés (o quizá, "Indeed"), es decir, que esta frase se traduce como

***Yes/Indeed, I've tried that***

¿Dónde radica el aspecto agresivo, y por qué es esta frase incorrecta? Entiendo completamente como un *énfasis* en 'yes' en inglés puede ser percibido como 'cansado' o 'exasperado', pero esto tiene mucho que ver con *cómo* se dice la palabra, es decir, la entonación....

¡Gracias por cualquier consejo!

Comment: It is not "yes, indeed". It's: Yes, I ***have*** tried that. Which can only be emphasized in speech, unless you use italics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sí se puede entender con esa connotación, porque tiene el sentido de

> (Ya te he dicho) que sí lo he probado

con ese `que` introduciendo una oración relativa que refiere a un **antecedente expreso** ([mira los usos de "que"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UkbUarn)). Y creo que esa es la clave. En "que sí/que no" se entiende que el antecedente (implícito) es "ya te he dicho", o si no no empezaríamos con un "que".

Por lo tanto, se carga a "que sí" con la connotación de "me estás insistiendo, aun cuando ya te he dado una respuesta - ya te he dicho 'sí'". Un "que sí" podría ser una respuesta válida a la segunda (como mínimo), tercera o sucesivas veces que alguien te pregunta. Pero si es la primera vez que te preguntan, y respondes con un "ya te he dicho que sí", la otra parte te dirá "No, no me los ha dicho. Esta es la primera vez que me respondes." y puede percibirse como que estás tenso o ansioso, y lo estás pagando con el otro.

Comment: Cansancio no es agresividad.

Comment: @Lambie, la percepción es que te **exaspera** la insistencia de la otra persona, y decir que "insisite" la primera vez que te pregunta algo, pues puede no ser "agresivo" (especialmente en el sentido de "violento) pero sí se percibe como un poco maleducado, en plan de "yo no he hecho nada para que pierdas la paciencia, no me respondas así".

Comment: Entre amigos, claro, señal que uno está un poco harto. Veo que la pregunta es más de traducción.....no creo que sea "mal educado". Puede también servir para hacer hincapie....

Answer (score 7):

*Yes/Indeed, I've tried that*

puede expresarse como

```
Sí, lo he probado.
Efectivamente, lo he probado.
```

El causante del tono agresivo es el "que". En mi opinión se interpreta como:

```
(Ya te he dicho) que sí lo he probado.
```